# Better way of writing a through type association

Tags: c#

in sql I have a table like:

```
PersonOrganisationRole
```

which has the columns:

```
PersonId, OrganisationId RoleId
```

So it's a three way table between Person, Organisation and Role.

So I was wanting to create a way to get all the Organisations a Person belongs to:

```
public class Person
{
  public IEnumerable<Organisation> Organisations
        {
            get 
            { 
                var organisations = new List<Organisation>();

                foreach (var personOrganisationRole in PersonOrganisationRoles.Where(personOrganisationRole => !organisations.Contains(personOrganisationRole.Organisation)))
                {
                    organisations.Add(personOrganisationRoles.Organisation);
                }

                return organisations;
            }
        }
}
```

So I'm basically populating a list by iterating through all items in the table and only adding the org if I haven't added it already. This is important because there could be multiple rows in the table with the same PersonId and OrganisationId due to the fact a person could have multiple roles at an organisation.

I'm thinking though there must be a far better way of writing this code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Keep in mind, that you need `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overridden on your `Organisation` object, for `Distinct` to work properly. By default .Net compares references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of the Linq Select() and Distinct() methods should do it.

```
 var organisations = PersonOrganisationRoles
              .Select<PersonOrganisationRoles,Organisation>(p => p.Organisation )
              .Distinct();
```

Comment: Easily the best solution. Nice and simple.

Comment: You probably don't need to explicitly specify the generic type parameters for `Select()` since they can be inferred from the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ's `Distinct` operator to do this unique-collecting, and `ToList` to collect the results in a list:

```
return PersonOrganisationRoles
    .Distinct(x => x.Organisation)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, use `.Distinct()` However, I would say don't call `.ToList()`.  Your function is returning an `IEnuerable`, so just return the `IEnumerable` that `.Distinct()` gives you.

Comment: Looks like a good way of doing this but the compilers complaining cannot resolve Organisation

Comment: In that case your example where `PersonOrganisationRole` has an `Organisation` property doesn't match your code. Check spelling etc. but the basic idea is that you want `Distinct` over some selector function like `x => x.Organisation`.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike: you're basically right, except that I find it a good practice to avoid returning lazy Enumerables from public methods to minimize risk of multiple iterations. If the OP knows exactly where that enumerable will be used and how they can of course leave it as a lazy enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<Organisation> Organisations
{
    get 
    { 
        return PersonOrganisationRoles
            .Select(por => por.Organisation)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

You will want to check that Organisation implements

- `GetHashcode` and `Equals` properly
- Optionally implements `IEquatable<Organisation>`

Distinct uses these to establish whether the item is already in the collection. (`Contains` did the same in the original sample, so that's probably what you intended)

Comment: This will not compile. You are returning List<PersonOrganisationRoles> and property demands IEnumerable<Organisation>.

Comment: @PetarRepac oops. Missed that, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function rather than property.

We are used to write objectInstance.PropertyName and usually think that this is fast operation that accesses some piece of data that is already in memory. In your case any call to Person.Organizations involves some processing and maybe even IO operations.

The other, possibly more important, point is that when I do:

```
var a = myPerson.Organizations;
var b = myPerson.Organizations;
```

I expect that a is pointing to the same List<> instance in memory as b.

And in your code that is not true. So please change the property to function or cache the result in private property so that processing is done only once. Like this:

```
public class Person
{
  private IEnumerable<Organisation> organizations; 

  public IEnumerable<Organisation> Organisations
  {
    get 
    { 
       if (organizations != null) return organizations;

       organisations = new List<Organisation>();
       // fill list here 
       return organisations;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how you've changed it from a property to a function there. Still looks like a property to me.

Comment: That peace of code is explaining hot to cache the result of getting organizations, that's what private field organizations is for. I leaved converting to function and IMO it is a better approach.

Comment: Making it a method rather than a property is good advice, but your answer doesn't really solve the OP's problem of collecting distinct instances.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. That was already answeded with LINQ and Distinct. Maybe I should write it as a comment instead.